# Clip out the part of an image in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, clipping-mask

How could I clip out the yellow part of the image below?

[image]

Here is what I tried.

1. Select the yellow part and the image itself.

   [image]
2. Go to Object->Clip->Set. And here is what I am getting.

[image]

As you can see my approach does not work.

So, I tried to reorder the layers of the image and the yellow part (move one above the other). Also tried to change the order in which I select the image and yellow part before clipping. All this did not help.

What else may I try and what could I miss here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to punch out the yellow shape from the brown, then you need to use *Path > Difference*.  For it to work you must select only two objects - the brown shape to be cut, and the yellow shape only.

Here's a simplified example

[image]